# I am trying to use Xpath to retrieve the script from a TV show, but it is returning an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

complete_script = tree.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')

print(complete_script)
```

I expected the entire (TV show) script to be displayed, but all I am getting is an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the `tbody` and directly scrape the table as:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
complete_script = tree.xpath('//table/tr[2]/td[2]//text()')
#to strip the characters from xml

results = [esc.strip() for esc in complete_script]
remove={'','&nbsp'}
results= [rem for rem in results if rem not in remove]

print(results)
```

But I would prefer BeautifulSoup to easily extract the same thing as

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
complete_script = soup.select('table > tr > td')[2].get_text()
print(complete_script)
```

Comment: Thank you! If the episode has a colon in the show's script, it stops the program. Do you know any way to get passed this?

Comment: the second episode stopped right? Try the code Now i've modified it a bit.

Comment: Several of them are stopping at some point throughout the script. The modified code worked! Is there also a way to do it with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: the second part given is in BeautifulSoup

Comment: The change was so subtle I hadn't even noticed. Are there ever disadvantages to using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Compared to lxml BeautifulSoup is SOOO slow but it has a lot of functions and is pretty straight forward

Comment: In your second-to-last line, how did you get `('table > tr > td')[2]`? By inspecting the element, I found the following three items, but I am unsure how to get the correct (yours) path.  copy selector: body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)  

copy JS path: document.querySelector("body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)")  

copy XPath: /html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]  (Is it possible to have beautiful formatting in a comment?)

Answer (score 1):

I would use bs4 4.7.1 and nth-of-type to get right td then stripped strings to loop and print out

Edit: From looking at @johnsnow06's answer (+), and wondering why when I used `get_text` I had a less well formatted output, I discovered it is due to my using `lxml` over `html.parser`.  So, my code below could be

```
print(soup.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').get_text())
```

provided the parser is 'html.parser'. The nbsp's are then removed as is need for loop.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for i in soup.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').stripped_strings:
    print(i.replace('&nbsp', ' '))
```

With other versions of bs4 you could use

```
lines = soup.select('td')[2]
for line in lines.stripped_strings:
    print(line.replace('&nbsp', ' '))
```

---

With xpath you want something more like:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
complete_script = tree.xpath('*//tr[2]/td[2]//text()')

for item in complete_script:
    print(item.replace('&nbsp', ' '))
```